# Is it true that probability is exhaustive while likelihood is not?

Tags: probability, statistics

In this web page :

https://www.psychologicalscience.org/observer/bayes-for-beginners-probability-and-likelihood

The author writes :

"Possible results are mutually exclusive and exhaustive.
...
Hypotheses, unlike results, are neither mutually exclusive nor exhaustive.
"

Is it true that possible results are exhaustive ?

For example, if we consider a continuum density probability, there is an infinite number of possible results, so aren't we "non exhaustive" ?

Comment: Why would that not be exhaustive?  Exhaustive simply means that all possibilities are covered.

Comment: But in a continuous pdf, there is infinite number of possibilities. isn't it contradicatory with the concept of exhaustive : that is that you could count.

Comment: "Exhaustive" doesn't mean countable.  It means inclusive.

Comment: All right. Thank you for your very useful explanation.